# Find number of sets for which $S_1 \subseteq S_2 \supseteq S_3 \subseteq ... $

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Find number of
$$ \langle S_1, S_2, ... , S_k \rangle $$
sequences of sets (each set $S_i \subset [n]$ for which

 a) $S_1 \subseteq S_2 \subseteq  S_3 \subseteq ... $

 b) $S_1 \subseteq S_2 \supseteq  S_3 \subseteq ... $

### My solution

for a)  and for example $k=3$ I wrote sum
$$ \sum _{r_1=0}^n \left(\sum _{r_2=0}^{r_1} \left(\sum _{r_3=0}^{r_2} \binom{r_2}{r_3} \binom{r_1}{r_2} \binom{n}{r_1}\right)\right) $$
and it can be proved that it is $$ 3^n $$ Generally we have $ k^n$.
But I totally don't see any pattern for $b$. Have somebody any idea?

Comment: In (a), for $k=1$ I get $2^n$ and in general I get $(k+1)^n$, not $k^n$.

Comment: In (a) the sequence $\langle S_1,\dots,S_k\rangle$ of sets is determined by specifying, for each $x\in[n]$, how many of the sets $S_1,\dots,S_k$ the element $x$ belongs to; that is, the sequence of sets is determined by a mapping $[n]\to\{0,1,\dots,k\}$.

Comment: For (b) it will be $b(k)^n$, we just have to find $b(k)$ by looking at a single element.  I get $b(1)=2, b(2)=3, b(3)=5$.